# Js on mousehover - find matching text from two divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousehover

I have a code that shows a couple of user names in two different divs.
The idea is for the user to find matching names or no matching names.

My idea is to make a function which acts like the browsers F3 button, but find matches on mousehover

Ex:

```
            <div id="fccStatus" class="col-md-6">
                <h2 style="text-align: center;color:white;">
                    Users you follow :
                </h2>
                <p id="a">a</p>
                <p id="b">b</p>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div id="links" class="col-md-6">
                <h2 style="text-align: center;color:white;">
                    Users who followed back :                    
                </h2>
                 <p id="a">a</p>
                <p id="b">b</p>
                <br>
            </div> 

    $( "#body" ).mouseover(function() {
       // find matching ids || text || classes .. e.t.c.
       });
```

Any ideas are much appreciated !

Comment: `#body` doesn't exist in the code you posted.

Comment: a little more detail needed, when you hover over div #1 or on either div?

Comment: And what does your attempt look like?

Comment: For HTML it doesn't look good having 2 DOM elements with the same id, first of all you need to correct that.

Comment: Apart of this question being too broad and missing any [mcve], I don't see any practical use for this feature. Sound like an unnecessary performance consuming feature

Comment: 1. #body is the id for the containing both divs
2. Either div
3. Same ids only as an example if that was a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the selector of jquery to find all the related elements, in this case we are matching all who has the same class that is on the current mouseover.

When it leaves it just change to the initial color.

You can use this same idea for match the text, classes etc.

I wouldn't recommend you to match same id's due to ids must be unique.

```js
$("p").mouseover(function() {
       // find matching ids || text || classes .. e.t.c.
       $("p."+$(this).attr("class")).css("color","red");
});
$("p").mouseleave(function() {
       // find matching ids || text || classes .. e.t.c.
       $("p."+$(this).attr("class")).css("color","black");
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fccStatus" class="col-md-6">
                <h2 style="text-align: center;color:white;">
                    Users you follow :
                </h2>
                <p class="a">a</p>
                <p class="b">b</p>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div id="links" class="col-md-6">
                <h2 style="text-align: center;color:white;">
                    Users who followed back :                    
                </h2>
                 <p class="a">a</p>
                <p class="b">b</p>
                <br>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
   <div id="fccStatus" class="col-md-6">
                <h2 style="text-align: center;color:white;">
                    Users you follow :
                </h2>
                <p id="a">a</p>
                <p id="b">b</p>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div id="links" class="col-md-6">
                <h2 style="text-align: center;color:white;">
                    Users who followed back :                    
                </h2>
                 <p id="a">a</p>
                <p id="b">b</p>
                <br>
            </div> 

    $( "#body" ).mouseover(function() {
       // find matching ids || text || classes .. e.t.c.
       });
       
       
       let divs = document.querySelectorAll('.col-md-6');
       divs.forEach(el=>{
       el.addEventListener('mouseenter',(){
       //somefunction
       });
 
       
       })
```